# Android ADB install "remote No space left on device" despite plenty of space available

Tags: android, adb

I tried to update an app via ADB but I get this error:

```
D:\apk>adb install -r app.apk
Performing Push Install
adb: error: failed to copy 'app.apk' to '/data/local/tmp/app.apk': remote No space left on device
app.apk: 0 files pushed. 56.0 MB/s (1179504 bytes in 0.020s)
```

df output on the device is:

```
Filesystem               Size     Used     Avail     Free   Blksize
/dev                   727.8M    64.0K   727.7M   727.7M   4096
/sys/fs/cgroup         727.8M    12.0K   727.8M   727.8M   4096
/mnt/secure            727.8M     0.0K   727.8M   727.8M   4096
/mnt/asec              727.8M     0.0K   727.8M   727.8M   4096
/mnt/obb               727.8M     0.0K   727.8M   727.8M   4096
/system                  1.9G   626.2M     1.3G     1.3G   4096
/data                    4.8G   262.2M     4.5G     4.6G   4096
/cache                 192.8M   160.0K   188.7M   192.7M   4096
/efs                    15.7M   132.0K    15.1M    15.5M   4096
/productinfo           928.0K    48.0K   780.0K   880.0K   4096
/preload                35.4M     3.6M    30.9M    31.7M   4096
/persdata/absolute       4.9M    48.0K     4.7M     4.9M   4096
/su                     90.5M   672.0K    87.9M    89.8M   4096
/mnt/shell/emulated      4.8G   283.2M     4.5G     4.5G   4096
```

I have three identical devices (I thought) and it worked on the other two. I can just restore a complete backup image of the device and I'm sure it will work fine again, but I want to understand where the error is coming from. I'm not that familiar with linux systems, so... any ideas?

This is a df of one of the devices where it worked fine, just for comparison:

```
Filesystem               Size     Used     Avail     Free   Blksize
/dev                   727.8M    64.0K   727.7M   727.7M   4096
/sys/fs/cgroup         727.8M    12.0K   727.8M   727.8M   4096
/mnt/secure            727.8M     0.0K   727.8M   727.8M   4096
/mnt/asec              727.8M     0.0K   727.8M   727.8M   4096
/mnt/obb               727.8M     0.0K   727.8M   727.8M   4096
/system                  1.9G   626.2M     1.3G     1.3G   4096
/data                    4.8G   553.7M     4.2G     4.3G   4096
/cache                 192.8M     1.2M   187.6M   191.6M   4096
/efs                    15.7M   124.0K    15.2M    15.6M   4096
/productinfo           928.0K    48.0K   780.0K   880.0K   4096
/preload                35.4M     3.6M    30.9M    31.7M   4096
/persdata/absolute       4.9M    40.0K     4.7M     4.9M   4096
/su                     90.5M   672.0K    87.9M    89.8M   4096
/mnt/shell/emulated      4.8G   574.7M     4.2G     4.2G   4096
```

I've already rebooted the device and wiped cache...

Thx :)

Comment: Okay, I just found out that I get the same error when adb push-ing files to /data or even booting TWRP recovery and trying to create a backup on /data ... However: Uploading files via MTP (Windows) to /data works fine in the OS and in TWRP recovery...